# Matching list of files (for a tv show) with episodes for that show

Tags: python, media, filenames, mediacenter

I would like to implement or find a library implementing a feature similar to that in Plex where it matches video files for a show to actual episodes for that show. What I have found so far:

- [Plex's scanner](http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/PlexNine_PMS_ScannerAgent) is closed source but based on XBMC.
- [XBMC's media **scraper**](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Scrapers) , I cannot seem to find a way to use it in my own project.
- [Boxee](http://support.boxee.tv/entries/172509-file-scanning-and-identification-progress) has a similar feature, but its vague on the details.
- [MythTV's scraper for theTvDb](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Ttvdb.py) is one part of the solution.
- [tvnamer](https://github.com/dbr/tvnamer) is a good start, but not mature enough.

I'm looking to target python or use python cbindings for c/c++ libraries.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also is there anything I should clarify?